# Making a horizontal list with clickable images as members

Tags: apache-flex

I want to make a horizontal list in my application, which will display images. While this is quite trivial, I want the image to open a flex alert box (the built in one) and display some text. For example, I will have an image of the .NET logo and I will enter some text somewhere (like in a collection), and this text will be displayed in the alert box.

How could I do this? There doesn't seem to be an event handler for clicking an item member in a flex horizontal list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to capture the selection of an item in a list, there are a number of events available to you:  itemClick, itemDoubleClick, change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" initialize="this_initialize()" creationComplete="this_creationComplete()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var images:Array;

            private function this_initialize():void
            {
                images = new Array();
                images.push("myimage1.jpg");
                images.push("myimage2.jpg");
                images.push("myimage3.jpg");
                images.push("myimage4.jpg");
                images.push("myimage5.jpg");
            }

            private function this_creationComplete():void
            {

            }

            private function list_itemClick(event:ListEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(event.currentTarget.selectedItem as String);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HorizontalList id="list" dataProvider="{images}" itemClick="list_itemClick(event)">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Image source="{data}" />
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:HorizontalList>

</mx:Application>
```

Is that what you're asking?  You need only hook into one of the list events (see the Flex docs for more info) to retrieve which item was selected.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Sine id="sineEasing"
                easeInFraction="0.3"/>
        <s:Power id="powerEasing"
                 exponent="8"/>

        <s:Animate id="anim" duration="500"  
                   effectStart="{trace('start');lock=true}"
                   effectEnd="{trace('end');lock=false}"
                   target='{viewport}' easer="{powerEasing}"  >
            <s:motionPaths>
                <s:SimpleMotionPath id="pth" property="horizontalScrollPosition"  />
            </s:motionPaths>
        </s:Animate>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="mydata3">
            <fx:String >page 1</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 2</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 3</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 4</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 5</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 6</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 7</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 8</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 9</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 10</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 11</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 12</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 13</fx:String>
            <fx:String >page 14</fx:String>


        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.DragEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            private const FUDGE_FACTOR:Number = 0.5;

            [Bindable] private var lock:Boolean= false;

            [Bindable] private var viewport ;
            [Bindable] private var max:int;
            [Bindable]protected var lstData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_0002.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt",source:"images/DSC_0003.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt3",source:"images/DSC_0008.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt3",source:"images/DSC_0009.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt3",source:"images/DSC_0010.JPG"},
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_00011.JPG"},
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_0011.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt3",source:"images/DSC_0012.JPG"},
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_0013.JPG"},
                {label:"nxt3",source:"images/DSC_0014.JPG"},
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_0015.JPG"},
                {label:"mmm",source:"images/DSC_0016.JPG"},
                ]);
            private function fudgeMouseWheel( event:MouseEvent ):void
            {
                trace('list.scroller.horizontalScrollBar.value'+list.scroller.horizontalScrollBar.value);
                event.delta *= FUDGE_FACTOR;    
                if( event.delta >0){
                    //list.scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition+=250;
                    if(!lock)  next();
                }else{
                    //list.scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition-=250;
                    if(!lock)  prev();
                }
                //trace('delta'+event.delta);
            } 


            protected function list1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.viewport = list.scroller.viewport;
                list.scroller.horizontalScrollBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, drag_handler);
                this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, fudgeMouseWheel, true );
                trace('list.scroller.viewport.contentWidth '+list.scroller.viewport.contentWidth );
                max=list.scroller.viewport.contentWidth-250;
                trace('max: '+ max);

            }
            private function drag_handler(e):void
            {
                trace('drag:'+list.scroller.horizontalScrollBar.value);
            }

            [Bindable] private var currentPos:int;


            protected function next():void
            {
                currentPos = list.scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition;
                pth.valueTo = currentPos+250;
                pth.valueFrom = currentPos;
                anim.play();
                scrollbar.value += 250;
                tempSliderPos += 250;
            }

            private function prev():void
            {
                currentPos = list.scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition;
                pth.valueTo = currentPos-250;
                pth.valueFrom = currentPos;
                anim.play();    
                scrollbar.value -= 250;
                tempSliderPos -= 250;
            }

            private var tempSliderPos:int=0;



            private function change( e ):void
            {
                //trace('e.target.value');
                /* if( e.target.value > tempSliderPos  )
                {
                pth.valueTo = tempSliderPos+250;
                pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                anim.play();    
                tempSliderPos+=250;

                }else{
                pth.valueTo = tempSliderPos-250;
                pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                anim.play();    
                tempSliderPos-=250;

                }  */

                /*  if( e.target.value > tempSliderPos  )
                {

                //if(!lock) next();
                pth.valueTo = tempSliderPos+250;
                pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                anim.play();    

                tempSliderPos+=250;

                }else{
                //if(!lock) prev();
                pth.valueTo = tempSliderPos-250;
                pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                anim.play();    
                tempSliderPos-=250;

                }*/

                //trace(e.target.value);
            }




            protected function scrollbar_changeStartHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //trace('start')
            }


            protected function scrollbar_changeEndHandler(e:Event):void
            {
                Event as FlexEvent;
                if( e.target.value > tempSliderPos  )
                {
                    trace('tempSliderPos '+tempSliderPos+' e.target.value '+e.target.value)
                    //if(!lock) next();
                    pth.valueTo = e.target.value;
                    pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                    anim.play();    

                    tempSliderPos = e.target.value;

                }else{
                    trace('tempSliderPos '+tempSliderPos+' e.target.value '+e.target.value)
                    //if(!lock) prev();
                    pth.valueTo = e.target.value;
                    pth.valueFrom = tempSliderPos;
                    anim.play();    
                    tempSliderPos = e.target.value;

                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!--<mx:HorizontalList id='list' 
                       width="250" height="281" 
                                dataProvider='{lstData}'
                                itemRenderer="list_item" 
                                x="216" y="48" 
                                creationComplete="list1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
        </mx:HorizontalList>-->


    <s:List id='list' skinClass="ListSkin" width="250" height="281" 
            dataProvider='{lstData}'
            itemRenderer="list_item" x="216" y="48" creationComplete="list1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    </s:List> 

    <s:HScrollBar id='scrollbar'   changeStart="scrollbar_changeStartHandler(event)"
                  changeEnd="scrollbar_changeEndHandler(event)"
                  stepSize="250"

                  width="250" minimum="0" maximum="{max}" x="216" y="382" change="{change(event)}" 
    snapInterval="250" />

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event handler to the image